# Hibernate CriteriaBuilder cannot compare 2 time - The data types time and datetime are incompatible in the greater than or equal to operator

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-criteria, criteriaquery

I am writing criteria query with compare 2 time.
As I run the service, an exception was thrown:

```
 2020-06-19 19:12:08.688 - WARN 27740 [ault-executor-0] o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper             : SQL Error: 402, SQLState: S0001
 2020-06-19 19:12:08.688 -ERROR 27740 [ault-executor-0] o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper             : The data types time and datetime are incompatible in the greater than or equal to operator.
```

Here is my entity definition:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@SuperBuilder
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@SelectBeforeUpdate
@TimeFlowValidation
@Table(name = "[PARKING_LOT]")
public final class ParkingLotEntity extends BaseEntity {

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "[PARKING_LOT_TYPE_ID]", referencedColumnName = "[ID]", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private ParkingLotTypeEntity parkingLotTypeEntity;

    @Column(name = "[LATITUDE]", nullable = false)
    private Double latitude;

    @Column(name = "[LONGITUDE]", nullable = false)
    private Double longitude;

    @Column(name = "[OPENING_HOUR]", nullable = false)
    private Time openingHour;

    @Column(name = "[CLOSING_HOUR]", nullable = false)
    private Time closingHour;

    @ColumnDefault("true")
    @Column(name = "[IS_AVAILABLE]")
    private Boolean isAvailable;
```

...

Here is JPA model gen:

```
@Generated(value = "org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor")
@StaticMetamodel(ParkingLotEntity.class)
public abstract class ParkingLotEntity_ extends com.bht.saigonparking.common.base.BaseEntity_ {

    public static volatile SingularAttribute<ParkingLotEntity, ParkingLotTypeEntity> parkingLotTypeEntity;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<ParkingLotEntity, Time> openingHour;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<ParkingLotEntity, Boolean> isAvailable;
    public static volatile SetAttribute<ParkingLotEntity, ParkingLotUnitEntity> parkingLotUnitEntitySet;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<ParkingLotEntity, ParkingLotLimitEntity> parkingLotLimitEntity;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<ParkingLotEntity, Double> latitude;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<ParkingLotEntity, Time> closingHour;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<ParkingLotEntity, ParkingLotInformationEntity> parkingLotInformationEntity;
    public static volatile SetAttribute<ParkingLotEntity, ParkingLotRatingEntity> parkingLotRatingEntitySet;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<ParkingLotEntity, Double> longitude;

    public static final String PARKING_LOT_TYPE_ENTITY = "parkingLotTypeEntity";
    public static final String OPENING_HOUR = "openingHour";
    public static final String IS_AVAILABLE = "isAvailable";
    public static final String PARKING_LOT_UNIT_ENTITY_SET = "parkingLotUnitEntitySet";
    public static final String PARKING_LOT_LIMIT_ENTITY = "parkingLotLimitEntity";
    public static final String LATITUDE = "latitude";
    public static final String CLOSING_HOUR = "closingHour";
    public static final String PARKING_LOT_INFORMATION_ENTITY = "parkingLotInformationEntity";
    public static final String PARKING_LOT_RATING_ENTITY_SET = "parkingLotRatingEntitySet";
    public static final String LONGITUDE = "longitude";

}
```

Here is my function:

```
 @Override
    public Long countAll(boolean isAvailable) {

        CriteriaQuery<Long> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Long.class);
        Root<ParkingLotEntity> root = query.from(ParkingLotEntity.class);

        return entityManager.createQuery(query
                .select(criteriaBuilder.count(root))
                .where(isAvailable
                        ? criteriaBuilder.and(
                        criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(ParkingLotEntity_.isAvailable), true),
                        criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get(ParkingLotEntity_.openingHour), criteriaBuilder.currentTime()),
                        criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get(ParkingLotEntity_.closingHour), criteriaBuilder.currentTime()))
                        : criteriaBuilder.or(
                        criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(ParkingLotEntity_.isAvailable), false),
                        criteriaBuilder.lessThan(root.get(ParkingLotEntity_.openingHour), criteriaBuilder.currentTime()),
                        criteriaBuilder.greaterThan(root.get(ParkingLotEntity_.closingHour), criteriaBuilder.currentTime()))))
                .getSingleResult();
    }
```

I think the problem is comparison with lessThan, greaterThan, lessThanOrEqual, greaterThanOrEqual.

I have follow the instruction on stackoverflow that add "sendTimeAsDateTime=false" to connection string, but it seem not working.

Some more information:
I am using MSSQL database and Hibernate 5.4.17 with Spring Boot and Spring Data Jpa.

Anything wrong with my implementation ? 
I am looking forward to hearing from you all. Thanks a lot !

Comment: What actually happens? And what should happen? Do you get an exception? Or unexpected results?